# Math.exp not working as expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I'm trying to make this formula work in javascript:

> 99 * exp(-0.0065 * (28 - *variable*)<sup>2</sup>)

I need the number returned to be an integer. This is what I have:

```
Math.round(99*(Math.exp(-0.0065*((28-variable)^2))))
```

If the variable were 28, I would expect a result of 99, but I get 98. When the variable is 18 I would expect 52; I get 94. When variable is 8, I expect 7 but get 86.

My variable will only ever be an integer ranging from -2 to 28.

I probably have the brackets in the wrong place or something, but I just can't see what I have done wrong.

Comment: Is `^2` in the formula really meant to be a bitwise XOR ...? I know it is commonly used to express "to the power of 2", in which case you'd actually want to use Math.pow()

Comment: @Cbroe Yes ^2 was me mistakenly thinking it meant to the power of two! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` in javascript is the bitwise XOR operator, not an exponent.

You are looking for `Math.pow` or `**` (ES7 - use the former for browsers):

```
Math.round(99 * Math.exp(-0.0065 * (28-variable) ** 2))
```

Now let's pull that into a function and test it with your expected outputs:

```js
const fn = n =>
  Math.round(99 * Math.exp(-0.0065 * (28-n) ** 2))

console.log(fn(28))
console.log(fn(18))
```

Comment: Thanks. That is it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(99 * Math.exp(-0.0065 * Math.pow(28-variable, 2)))
```

Try this instead. `^` is a bitwise XOR. `Math.pow` is the function you are seeking.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts apologies I copy and pasted the OP's code and added Math.pow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.pow` instead of `^`

```
Math.round(99 * Math.exp(-0.0065 * Math.pow(28 - variable, 2)))
```

For more infos expressions and operators, check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

`^` is used for XOR operations, you need to use `Math.pow` instead

```
Math.round(99*(Math.exp(-0.0065*(Math.pow((28-variable),2)))))
```